# Drawn lines on panel dissapear when scrollbars are shown

Tags: c#, css, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a panel where the AutoScroll property is tru(AutoSize is false). Using a variable Graphics g i draw some lines on this panel. The problem is when the ScrollBars appear, all the lines that created during the execution, dissapear. Any idea why and some possible solution??

I tried to use another panel where i could draw the lines, setting its backcolor to trasparent but didn't seem too good because other stuff i have like textboxes etc are hiding from the new panel

Here is some of my code and some screenshots hoping they will help!
Thank you

```
 private void fwd_exmem_hazard()
    {
        int poss = 0;
        int poss2 = poss+1;
        List<mystruct> pipe = new List<mystruct>();
        pipe = queue1.ToList();
        while (poss2 < fwd1_list.Count)
        {
            try
            {
                if (((fwd1_list[poss].cycle == 3) && (fwd1_list[poss].rd == fwd1_list[poss2].rs) && (fwd1_list[poss].reg_write) && (fwd1_list[poss].rd != 0))
                    || (fwd1_list[poss].cycle == 3 && (fwd1_list[poss].rd == fwd1_list[poss2 + 1].rs) && (fwd1_list[poss].reg_write) && (fwd1_list[poss].rd != 0)))
                {

                    Graphics g; g = panel3.CreateGraphics();
                    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
                    Point p1 = new Point(pipe[poss].location.X+30, pipe[poss].location.Y);
                    Point p2 = new Point(pipe[poss2].location.X-10, pipe[poss2].location.Y);
                    g.DrawLine(pen,p1, p2);
                    fwd_count++;
                }
                if (((fwd1_list[poss].cycle == 3) && (fwd1_list[poss].rd == fwd1_list[poss2].rt) && (fwd1_list[poss].reg_write) && (fwd1_list[poss].rd != 0))
                    || (fwd1_list[poss].cycle == 3 && (fwd1_list[poss].rd == fwd1_list[poss2 + 1].rt) && (fwd1_list[poss].reg_write) && (fwd1_list[poss].rd != 0)))
                {

                    Graphics g; g = panel3.CreateGraphics();
                    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Orange);
                    Point p1 = new Point(pipe[poss].location.X+30, pipe[poss].location.Y);
                    Point p2 = new Point(pipe[poss2].location.X-10, pipe[poss2].location.Y);
                    g.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
                    fwd_count++;

                }
                poss++; poss2++;
            }
            catch { break; }
        }

    }
```

mystruct is a custom structure i created, queue1 is a global Queue

[image: Before scrollbars appear]

[image: after scrollbars appear]

Comment: You will have to restructure your drawing completely! - Whatever you paint onto a `Panel` (or any other Control) __needs__ to be painted in the `Paint` event. After you have created the data (probably in variables at class level) from which the event drawing methods can work, e.g: `e.Graphics.DrawLine(..)` you call `Panel.Invalidate()`

Comment: Once you have moved the drawing stuff where it belongs you may have to [adapt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406720/paint-on-panel-allowing-auto-scroll?rq=1) for the scrolling..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does text drawn on a panel disappear?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946150/why-does-text-drawn-on-a-panel-disappear)

Answer (score 0):

Thats happening because when the panel refreshes it calls paint event and redraws itself from scratch, thus your lines disappear, so you need to place your code in Panel Paint event.